# How do I set the Banshee context menu to move to trash instead of delete from drive?

Tags: banshee

I am using Banshee as my media player.  When I right click a track, the context menu has a 'delete from drive' option.  When I use this, it deletes the file.  I would like for the file to be sent to trash (recycle bin) instead.  Is there a way to do this, or a plugin or extension for this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to do this within Banshee. I don't know of any extensions that add this functionality -- it may be out of the scope of an extension.

It has been reported to the Banshee team, though, so if you're interested in staying up-to-date with the issue, it's tracked here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=545937

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow this!  I wonder if an extension could be written for this purpose, though I imagine it wouldn't be straightforward to use.